# How to export from MS access to DBF as integer?

Tags: microsoft-access, database, export

I have a DB in access format and I have to export data in dBASE III (*.dbf) but I do not understad why it export all the integer numerbs like N,00000

All the colum are set as integer and there are no decimal digits

Answer (score 0):

There is no Integer data type in dBase. it is Numeric or Float data types. Access converts long Integers to Numeric data type in dBase. So try and set your export to use DECIMAL, specify your digits and decimal places, then import only the integer part of your data to the corresponging field, and the decimals to a dummy field (maybe separate db), after that append your result to the original tables.